# Using numpy on an embedded python interpreter using VS2008 under Windows 7

Tags: c++, python-2.7, visual-studio-2008, numpy, windows-7

Let's take a look at my project.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, Python 2.7 and numpy 1.8.1 (but I have tried several versions and none worked). My project is being compiled on debug mode.

It's a very simple code:

```
/* = Main.cpp file = */
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Python.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *main;
    Py_Initialize();

    pName = PyUnicode_FromString("main");
    main = PyImport_Import(pName);

    Py_XDECREF(pName);

    if (main != NULL) 
    {
        printf("Python Module Loaded!!\n");
    }
    else  
    {
        printf("Unable to load Python Module!!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And

```
""" = Main.py file = """
print 'Hello World!'
```

If I execute this code, I get:

[image: Code Output]

As it is expected.

My problem arises as soon as I change main.py into:

```
""" = Main.py file = """
import numpy
print 'Hello World!'
```

Then I get the:

[image: Code output]

I have tried to run main.py separately on a python interpreter (not embedding it into C++) and then everything works just fine:

[image: Code output]

I have also tried a modification on the main.cpp as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Python.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *main;
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy");

    return 0;
}
```

From this code the output is:

[image: Code output]

Finally I also tried compiling original version of main.cpp code in release mode and then the output is:
[image: Code output]

So, my question here is: What can I do to get numpy working under debug compilations using an embedded interpreter on Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know you have to have use a python debug version built don't you? That is probably your problem. (I would leave a comment but no rep ):   )